# Invisible crash (no stack trace) between startActivity() and onCreate()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an annoying crash : I'm not even sure how to call it, my application closes without displaying any messages (0.5s black screen then desktop) and there seem not to have any `RunTimeException`, at least none displayed in my android console.

```
 Intent intent = MainPagerActivity.newIntent(AuthActivity.this, mHome, mNewsFeed);
 try {
      startActivity(intent);
 } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
      Log.i("renaud", " hello ");
 }
 //finish() //<= the bug is there with or without this
```

here no stacktrace's exeptions are written, my "hello" log is sent, no problem.

`MainPagerActivity`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("renaud", "hello again");
    ...
```

"hello again" is never displayed.

Note that this does not append with all my users, just one that must have something  different somewhere, but nothing that I could see.

what could happend there ? Is there a step between startActivity and "onCreate" that I'm missing ?

thank you all,

---

Edit :

`MainPagerActivity`

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context c, HomeFeed hf, NewsFeedV2 nf) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(c, MainPagerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(HomeFeed.SERIALIZATION_NAME, hf);
    intent.putExtra(NewsFeed.SERIALIZATION_NAME, nf);
    return intent;
}
```

HomeFeed and NewsFeedV2 implements Serializable.

Comment: Where do you start the intent?

Comment: What are you passing between activities? Serializables or parcelables? Make sure you're not exceeding the limited size

Comment: What does `MainPagerActivity.newIntent()` method do?

Comment: Hello, thx for the quick replies. 

- 1 - I start the intent from a Thread launched from the UI thread (new Thread(new Runnable(){..}).start. This is because he is waiting for a countDownLatch to get to 0. 
 - 2 - I know that this is dirty and I've changed it for the next version (this appends in production), but I pass larges Serializable objects, this could be the issue here, how to I know if it's the problem ?. 
- 3 - I'll edit my original post to show you the intent construction.

Comment: Change from serializable to parcelable :) If they are really large objects then use a singleton architecture that saves the data for the other activity to use

Comment: In the new architecture, I use Realm so I won't ever again pass anything but IDs from one activity to an other. Is this really a consistent behaviour ? if data is too large, it crashes without further informations ?